# Bluetooth Watch that can control the music playback of an android device?

Tags: bluetooth, music, remote-control, android-wear

I know shopping questions are kind of offtopic here, but for the life of me, I cannot find a bluetooth watch that can control the music playback of the phone.

I've seen watches that sync the music from the phone to the watch and all that, but I don't need that! I don't want music in my watch, I want to be able to leave my phone connected to some speakers, and control the music from the watch.

Most bluetooth earphones can control this, so it should be deadly easy to create an app that does this from the watch!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that all Android Wear watches can control a music player. I own a Moto 360, and whenever i launch GPM to play some music, a card appears on my watch to control it. This should be the case with any music player available on Android.